# Change a date in google-scripts so it is less than or equal to instead of just equal to

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am super new to javascript, so sorry ahead of time! I have a code that I want to send an email reminder when a date on my google-sheet is less than or equal to current date. Right now it is just equal to.

I have tried to change = to <= but then the code does not work

```
cellValue = row[2];// date specified in cell C

if (!cellValue) {continue;}//If there is no cell value continue looping

if (typeof cellValue === 'object') {
reminderDate = cellValue.toLocaleDateString();
} else {
cellValue = new Date(cellValue);//Convert date as string to object
reminderDate = cellValue.toLocaleDateString();
}

if (reminderDate != today)      // Skip this reminder if not for today
  continue;
```

Comment: Can you give some more details? I might can help you :)

Comment: Hello! long story short; I work in a doctors office and I want to send email reminders from my google sheet to my doctors when they are within 45-days of needing to be re-credentialed.

Comment: I see. Wich part is responsible for checking when to send the email?

Comment: Review questions about "date comparison in JavaScript" -- you don't want to compare them as strings!

Comment: To compare dates, you need to convert them to milliseconds, as in the sample provided below by Cooper

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if (row[2]) {
  var reminderDate=new Date(new Date(row[2]).getFullYear(),new Date(row[2]).getMonth(),new Date(row[2]).getDate()).getTime();
  var today=new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate()).getTime();
  if(reminderDate<today)continue;
}
```